# creat a tuple by removing first element from another tuple in ML

Tags: tuples, sml, ml

using ML as a programming language we have list  and tuple, in the case of lists we can form a list from another list by removing or appending elements from and to the original list, for example if we have:

```
val x = [7,8,9] : int list
```

in REPL we can do some operations like the following:

```
- hd x;
val it = 7 : int
- tl x;
val it = [8,9] : int list
```

now if we have a tuple lets say:

```
val y = (7,8,9) :int*int*int
```

now the question is that , can we have a smaller tuple by removing the first element from the original tuple ? in other words , how to remove `(#1 y)` and have new tuple `(8,9)` in a similar way that we do it in the case of list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Tuples are very different from lists. With lists, size need not be known at compile time, but with tuples, not only should the number of elements be known at compile time, the type of each element is independent of the others.

Take the type signature of `tl`:

```
- tl;
val it = fn : 'a list -> 'a list
```

It is `'a list -> 'a list` - in other words `tl` takes a `list` of `'a` and returns another one. Why don't we have one for tuples as well? Assume we wanted something like

```
y = (1,2,3);
tail y;        (* returns (2,3) *)
```

Why does this not make sense? Think of the type signature of `tail`. What would it be?
In this case, it would clearly be

```
'a * 'b * 'c -> 'b * 'c
```

Takes product of an `'a`, a `'b` and a `'c` and returns a product of 
a `'b` and a `'c`. In ML, all functions defined must have a statically determined 
type signature. It would be impossible to have a `tail` function for tuples that 
**handles all possible tuple sizes**, because each tuple size is essentially a *different type*.

```
'a list
```

Can be the type of many kinds of lists: `[1,2,3,4]`, or `["A", "short", "sentence"]`, or 
[true, false, false, true, false]. In all these cases, the value of the type 
variable `'a` is bound to a different type. (int, string, and bool). And `'a list` can be a list of any size.

But take tuples:

```
(1, true, "yes");   (* (int * bool * string) *)
("two", 2)          (* (string, int) *)
("ok", "two", 2)    (* (string, string, int) *)
```

Unlike list, these are all of different types. So while the type signature of all lists is simple (`'a list`), there is no 'common type' for all tuples - a 2-tuple has a different type from a 3-tuple.

So you'll have to do this instead:

```
y = (7, 8, 9);
(a, b, c) = y;
```

and `a` is your head and you can re-create the tail with `(b,c)`.
Or create your own tail:

```
fun tail (a,b,c) = (b, c)
```

This also gives us an intuitive understanding as to why such a function would not make sense: If is impossible to define a single `tail` for use across all tuple types:

```
fun tail (a,b) = (b)
  | tail (a,b,c) = (b, c)  (* won't compile *)
```

You can also use the `#` shorthand to get at certain elements of the tuple:

```
#1 y;   (* returns 7 *)
```

But note that `#1` is not a function but a compile time shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

Lists and tuples are immutable so there is no such thing like removing elements from them.

You can construct a new tuple by decomposing the original tuple. In SML, the preferred way is to use pattern matching:

```
fun getLastTwo (x, y, z) = (y, z)
```

If you like `#n` functions, you can use them as well:

```
val xyz = (7, 8, 9)
val yz = (#2 xyz, #3 xyz) (* (8, 9) *)
```

Comment: maybe the last line has to be val yz = (#2 xyz, #3 xyz)  (* (8, 9) *) instead of  val yz = (#2 xys, #3 xyz)  (* (8, 9) *).